# How to override CSS file in custom theme in magento 2

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, I have create new theme. I tried to add less file app/design/frontend/mage_vender/sample(theme)/web/css/source‌​/_extend.less.
But it is not showing changes.
 Please can anyone tell me, how can we do ?
 I am using magento 2.1.3 
Thank you

Comment: Have you added your new theme to the themes.js?

Comment: no, How can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to create your theme, don't forget to add all the required files like the `theme.xml` and `registration.php`. Last time I checked the magento 2 documentation it was up to date and had enough information regarding on how to create new themes.

Second thing you need to do is to add your new theme to the theme.js, other wise you will not be able to compile your new less files into CSS. You do this by adding a new json group into `/dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js`

Now to override less files for example lets says the _navigation.less you just need to put it under `/app/design/frontend/[YOUR_THEME]/web/css/source/_navigation.less`

Then do a `grunt refresh`, you do this always when you add new files and `grunt watc`h if you're editing one that has already been added.

Comment: Hello Andre, I followed these steps but it is not working here :(

Comment: Please can you tell me why it is not working, I used this Json group sample: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Magestore/sample',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/source/_extend'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    }

Answer (score 0):

We have another way to do it.

First, create a new less file and then add it inside your _extend.less file like below.

```
@import 'theme/slick.less';
```

After that, if you use grunt then need to do the below things.

```
/dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js
<theme_name>: {
area: 'frontend',
name: '/',
locale: en_US,
files: [
'<path_to_file1>', //path to root source file ex: css/styles-m
'<path_to_file2>' ex: 'css/styles-l'
],
dsl: 'less'
```

After adding the above please run the below commands.

```
grunt clean:theme
grunt exec:theme
grunt less:theme
chmod 0777 -R var/*
chmod 0777 -R pub/*
chmod 0777 -R generated/*
grunt watch
```

Please check and let us know if you still facing any issues.